# Disable subdomain tracking on Segment

Tags: subdomain, analytics, segment, event-tracking

We have a SAAS business with Analytics.js' Segment library install on `domain.com` (with API key `X`) and `a.domain.com` (with API key `Y`).

When a user logs itself on domain.com, **Segment** is setting a cookie `*.domain.com` that is read to keep user_id and sessions.
When this logged user is going to a.domain.com, it is recognized as a logged user by reading the cookie `*.domain.com`. This is called subdomain tracking and it seems to be enabled by default by **Segment**, and we don't want that happening.

Anyone encoutered the same issue ? Reaching Segment's support is useless as we're not prioritary for support.

We're considering removing Analytics.js library on `a.domain.com` and hitting Segment's API with requests, but it would mean computing all default Segment properties (such as anonymous_id, user_agent, etc...). It would be time consuming and hard to maintain.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: I'm facing the same issue here. Did you solve this one?